# Prove this partition of the plane is not a foliation

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

Let us define a partition of the plane as follows: for the points $(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0\leq0$ we have leaves that are straight lines ($y=y_0$) and for $y_0>0$ we have leaves $e^{x+\operatorname{ln}y_0-x_0}$. This is indeed a partition. But I am being asked whether it is a foliation.

A rank $k$ foliation is a collection $\{L_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ of leaves of a connected immersed submanifold such that it forms a partition of that manifold and for every point of the manifold there exists a chart $(U,\phi=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $U\cap L_\alpha$ is a countable union of slices $\{x_{k+1}=\text{ constant},\ldots,x_n=\text{ constant}\}$ or empty.

Now I do not believe the given partition is a foliation and that the problem lies on the $y=0$ line. When we take a chart around $(x_0,0)$ we have leaves which are lines and leaves which are exponential curves, which will contradict the continuity of $\phi$ the homeomorphism of the chart, I think. But I do not know how to rigorously prove this.

**edit:** The Frobenius theorem tells us that there exists a bijection between foliations and involutive distributions which maps a foliation to a distribution $D$, where $D_p := T_pL_\alpha$ for all $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $L_\alpha$ is the leaf through $p$. 
A distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subbundle of $T\mathbb{R}^2$. Lemma 10.32 of Lee gives us a good criterium for subbundles. It says that in our case, we have a subbundle if and only if for every $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ on which there exists sections $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_m: U\rightarrow T\mathbb{R}^2$ with the property that $\sigma_1(q),\ldots,\sigma_m(q)$  form a basis for $D_q$ at each $q\in U$.

The tangent space to a leaf at a point $(x,y)$ will be a straight line with slope $y$ if $y>0$ and slope $0$ if $y\leq 0$. They are linear spaces of dimension $1$. What we wanted to show is that for a neighborhood around $(0,0)$ (or some other point on $y=0$), there is no smooth section such that the above property holds. I believe a continuous section always exists, but I am not sure how to show whether it is smooth or not.

Comment: Is your chart supposed to be $C^1$? It might help to write down the $1$-form $\omega$ so that the leaves are given by $\omega=0$. For $y\le 0$, we can take $\omega = dy$. What about for $y>0$?

Comment: The only restriction on the chart $(U,\phi)$ is that $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ is a homeomorphism (bijective, open and continuous) for some subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $m$. I think $\omega$ will be $-e^xdx+dy$ for $y>0$, since we get the leaves when the change in $y$ equals the change in $x$ times $e^x$? I am not sure I see how the theory of forms corresponds to foliations however;

Comment: That's close, but not quite right. It should be $\omega = dy-y\,dx$ for $y>0$. If you have a foliation, you should have local coordinates $(u,v)$ in which you can write $\omega = f\,du$ for some function $f$. It's pretty clear that there are no $C^1$ such local coordinates. But I don't even know how to talk about $1$-forms (or tangent lines to curves) if I'm only in $C^0$ coordinates. But I'm pretty sure you can straighten out the family of curves locally with a $C^0$ coordinate system.

Comment: You did not state any smoothness requirements on $\phi$. I'm guessing that is an unintended omission, because there is indeed a standard concept of $C^0$ foliations, and this example is indeed a $C^0$-foliation. If you make no smoothness requirements on $\phi$, requiring only that it be a homeomorphism (in this case from an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ to an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$) then that's more or less the definition of a $C^0$ foliation. And this example can be obtained using a single, global chart defined by a certain homeomorphism $\phi : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: This is not an answer, due to the differential-geometry tag. But, it's a $C^0$ foliation with a single coordinate chart $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, namely the homeomorphism
$$\phi(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
(x,y e^{-x}) & \quad\text{if $y > 0$} \\
(x,y)        & \quad\text{if $y \le 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Leaves in the lower half plane are horizontal lines of the form $y=C$. Leaves in the upper half plane are of the form $y e^{-x} = C$, equivalently $y = C e^x$, which is equivalent to the given form $y = e^{x + \ln(y_0)-x_0}$ by setting $C = e^{\ln(y_0)-x_0} = y_0 e^{-x_0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it is a foliation. By the global Frobenius theorem, it will correspond to an involutive distribution $D$. Where $D_p$ is given by $T_pL_\alpha$, where $L_\alpha$ is the leaf through $p$. So $D$ is a subbundle of the tangent bundle which means in particular that for a neighborhood $U$ around $(0,0)$ we have a smooth section $\sigma: U\rightarrow T\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\{\sigma(q)\}$ forms a basis for $D_q$ for $q\in U$.

Now if $q= (q_1,q_2)$ and $q_2>0$, $D_q$ will be the straight line with slope $q_2$ since $\frac{d}{dx}e^{x+\operatorname{ln}q_2-q_1}= q_2$. If $q_2\leq 0$, $D_q$ will be the straight line with slope $0$. But this means clearly that $\sigma$ can never be smooth since its first derivative will have a discontinuity. Indeed, $\sigma$ will be of the form $q\mapsto (\lambda_q, \lambda_qq_2)$ where $\lambda_q$ is a smooth function from $q$ to an element of $\mathbb{R}$. Deriving the second component, we see that there is a discontinuity for $q_2 = 0$. Hence, $\sigma$ is not smooth.